# Undocumented merging behaviour of rule-based output in `MovingMap`

Tags: list-manipulation

In addition to the functions with a single-value output, `MovingMap` also allows the functions with rule-based structure to hold multi-value outputs for times within each window:
[`MovingMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingMap.html):[image]

However, how the multi-value output is merged into the final result of `MovingMap` is undocumented.

Can someone explain this? And, is there possible risk when using the multi-value function as mapping functions in `MovingMap`?

Comment: have you looked at the examples under `Scope` `Functions` ?

Comment: Hi @george2079, yes, I did. But the last example under that section doesn't indicate the way how the outputs of each window are merged. That's the point of this question.

Comment: Having looked further I find the docs pretty obtuse.  Maybe better if you had a specific example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I revisited this problem and found an answer to this question I raised days ago:

```
ts = Table[{i, RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"]]}, {i, 6}];
MovingMap[(v = g/@RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 3]; #Times -> v)&, ts, 2]
```

The results indicate `MovingMap` will take averages of values held in each rule-based window as the output:

```
{{1, g["o"]}, {2, 1/2 (g["f"] + g["w"])}, {3, 1/3 (g["b"] + g["d"] + g["f"])}, {4, 1/3 (g["g"] + g["u"] + g["w"])}, {5, 1/2 (g["h"] + g["u"])}, {6,g["x"]}}
```

Although if such treatment is approapriate or not is open to be debated, I think a clearer explanation could be added to the documentation as an example. Otherwise, I feel less secure when using `MovingMap` in this way.